# What does たく mean when used by itself at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: colloquial-language, slang

In the Video Game, Persona 4 Golden, Dojima says the following after recieving a phone call:

たく…誰だ、こんな時に。

Now, I know this roughly translates to "Who is it at this time?" but what does たく mean at the start?

My first guess by the way he said is that it means something similar to "Darn" or "Damn it" or it might just be a noise people use when they're surprised. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It is like the same thing happening to まったく as in *Okay* sounding *'kay*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> たく…誰だ、こんな時に。
>
> Jesus Christ! Who has a nerve to call at this time?!?

You are right on nuance. This たく is short for **まっ**たく. まったく is one of the interjections you use to express frustration or annoyance. The possible translations are "damn it," "my god," "Jesus Christ" and many others.